# Search word in Trie?

Tags: java, trie

I have a Trie in Java, and I want search if cointains a word.

For example: Trie: [casa-perro-animal], hogar = false; casa = true;

```
public boolean search (String word){
    /**Method to complete**/
}
```

And the class Trie with Node:

```
public class Trie {
/**
 * Clase auxiliar para guardar caracteres que forman parte de una palabra
 * @author zenon
 */
protected class Info {
    char c;    // Caracter actual
    Info alt;  // Caracter alternativo para la misma posición
    Info next; // Caracter que es la primera opción en la siguiente posición

    public Info(char c, Info alt, Info next) {
        this.c = c;
        this.alt = alt;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

protected Info root; // Referencia al punto de inicio de la estructura
```

Any help? I am spanish. Thank you very much.

Comment: use contains method of String class

Comment: Is without use contains method, create my own method.

Comment: You will get much more out of a programming class if you try and solve the problem yourself, instead of asking others to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at [doubly chained tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-child_right-sibling_binary_tree) implementation of Trie:

<sub>[image and description from wikipedia's entry on Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)</sub>

[image: Doubly chained tree implementation of Trie]

<sub>Vertical arrows are child pointers, dashed horizontal arrows are next pointers. The set of strings stored in this trie is `{baby, bad, bank, box, dad, dance}`. The lists are sorted to allow traversal in lexicographic order</sub>

### How to search it

Your search has to consume the characters one by one of the searched `word` and navigate the trie.

Take the first character and check whether your root contains it. If yes, you can move to next character in the `word` and down along the solid arrow to the next node of the current **list** - in your implementation it's the `next` node of type `Info`. This way you are traversing within the same **list** downwards (according to the diagram above).

If the current node does not contain the character you are searching for, you move horizontally across to the next alternative **list** (along the dotted lines). In your case this is represented by the `alt` `Info` node. And you repeat the test for the same letter there. If no luck, move to the next alternative list again.

If you have checked all alternative **lists** at a given level without any match, and are facing a dead end (where `alt == null`), you can conclude that the `word` is not contained within your **trie**.

Conversely if you have consumed all characters from the `word` and are at the last node within a **list** (i.e. `next == null`), then you can conclude that the `word` is stored within the **trie**.